# Ubuntu 22 'lost' all devices after morning boot; lspci still shows them; not a HW issue, because Live DVD loads correctly

Tags: boot, drivers, devices, lspci

**EDIT**: Suspicious log entries are added at the end of the post.

**NOTE**: this is NOT a hardware problem. I booted up an Ubuntu installation media, all the devices work as they should.
I would like to get my local SSD installation to work like before. New installation is not an option at this moment for many reasons (and time is the most important of them).

**PC**: Intel 3770, Kingston SSD 1TB, RAM 16GB, GTX970, 2 monitors, wire KB and mouse) with Ubuntu 22 with all the latest updates.
Enough free space.
No hardware changes, no new apps.

*Just powered it off yesterday and powered it on in the morning.*

What I see when boot is ready is the following: second monitor does not receive a signal; first monitor resolution is low (somewhat around 1024x768).
Both keyboard and mouse work.
I go to display settings, it says 'Unknown Monitor' and I can not change resolution (I am 100% sure it had 'BenQ Monitor' name before).
I decide to reboot and see the same.
At that moment I thought this is the monitor/cable issue and reconnected both monitors, as well as KB.
When I boot to the OS this time, only mouse works. KB does not. I can enable Accessibility and type in my password.
lspci shows all the devices (detects nvidia card, VIA USB, etc).

After that I rebooted probably 50 times, trying different options. No result.
A few observations:

- I can go to Shift menu and choose different kernels, but no changes.
- When I go to BIOS, both mouse and KB work. After boot, only mouse works.
- Boot screen (UEFI having MB logo and Ubuntu logo) has low resolution as well. I am sure it was a normal (fit monitor native resolution) before.
- If I plug in any other device (KB, Mouse, SSD via USB) it is visible in BIOS, but not recognized by Ubuntu. I did not try to remove the mouse which is still working; I believe it will stop working once I do that.

At this moment I think some file was damaged or I need to somehow re-initialize the hardware scan or something like that, but googling and asking chatgpt did not give me any advice.
I am good with terminal commands, but when it comes to the peripherals and issues like this, I have no idea what to do.

I have a backup of the home dir, so I am not afraid of losing my data, but there are tons of the apps I will have to reinstall or reconfigure, which I do not have time to do now.

Please advise.

Before shutdown:

```
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6971]: (EE) event5  - Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 35ms, your system is too slow
```

Log spammed with (all keycodes):

```
gnome-shell[7159]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
gnome-shell[7159]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
gnome-shell[7159]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
```

AFTER BOOT:

```
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6971]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @2560x1440 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=2560x1440, ViewPortOut=2560x1440+0+0}"
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6971]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[6971]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"

gsd-color[7269]: failed to set xrandr-BenQ Corporation-BenQ LCD-M8K00722019 color transform matrix: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: The requested configuration is based on stale information

systemd-udevd[373]: event5: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0xc022d, and key code 103: Invalid argument
systemd-udevd[362]: controlC1: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
systemd-udevd[368]: sdb: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb' failed with exit code 1

systemd-udevd[380]: sdb1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb1' failed with exit code 1.
systemd-udevd[388]: sdb2: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb2' failed with exit code 1.



kernel: [    3.522661] input: A4TECH USB Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6.3/2-1.6.3:1.0/0003:09DA:9090.0001/input/input6
kernel: [    3.522953] hid-generic 0003:09DA:9090.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [A4TECH USB Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6.3/input0
kernel: [    3.523094] input: A4TECH USB Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6.3/2-1.6.3:1.1/0003:09DA:9090.0002/input/input7
kernel: [    3.523306] hid-generic 0003:09DA:9090.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [A4TECH USB Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6.3/input1
kernel: [    3.553358] input: Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6.1/2-1.6.1.2/2-1.6.1.2:1.0/0003:045E:00DB.0003/input/input8
kernel: [    3.610732] microsoft 0003:045E:00DB.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6.1.2/input0
kernel: [    3.610934] input: Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6.1/2-1.6.1.2/2-1.6.1.2:1.1/0003:045E:00DB.0004/input/input9
kernel: [    3.670743] microsoft 0003:045E:00DB.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6.1.2/input1


/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: #011Using a default monitor configuration.

/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: vesa: Refusing to run on UEFI
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: #011"Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: EFI VGA (video memory: 3072kB)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (DB) xf86MergeOutputClassOptions unsupported bus type 0
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1024x768 (pitch 1024)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 78.7 MHz, 59.9 kHz, 75.7 Hz
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0   78.65  1024 1056 1184 1312  768 772 776 792 -hsync -vsync -csync (59.9 kHz b)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
```

AFTER BOOT - SPAMMED WITH (different device names, such as Microsoft Natural Keyboard etc):

```
 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device A4TECH USB Device (/dev/input/mouse0)
 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3188]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

```
 gnome-session[3318]: libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
 gnome-session[3287]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GLES Helper exited with code 512
 gnome-session[3284]: gnome-session-binary[3284]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
 gnome-session[3284]: gnome-session-binary[3284]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
 gnome-session-binary[3284]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
 gnome-session-binary[3284]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
```

Comment: Look through `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/kern.log` and `sudo dmesg` for clues.

Comment: Thank you, added a few entries from the logs. Looks like the devices are detected correctly, but for some reason are not used.

Comment: All errors appear to be somehow connected to the X server. Can you log into a Wayland session?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: not a real solution, but the probable cause was found.

I did not solve the drivers issue, so this is not the real answer to the question of how to bring back all the devices, but the situation resolved the following way.

I was basically forced to install a fresh Ubuntu, and it turns out my GTX970 started dying, which somehow caused the behavior described in the topic. gnome-shell on fresh Ubuntu started crashing with the messages related to the graphic card or drivers (note: I tried both community and nvidia), such as 'The nvidia probe routine was not called' etc.

After replacing the graphic card with Radeon 580, no issues whatsoever for 2 days.
Tried old Ubuntu and unfortunately it did not work, but as I have already mentioned, I did not want to leave the topic unanswered, so if anyone faces the same devices disappearance, it might be your HW, and Live DVD can not be a good measurement tool of your HW working in such case.